# Orc and Light Armor

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Trying to play as Orc in Skyrim, the character would be a sort of dual 1 handed fighter using bows too, between warrior and thief so to speak.

I would be sneaking sometimes, but I would want to use blacksmithing too.

What kind of armor should I pick? Light or Heavy? Is it cool to have an Orc in Glass armor? Btw I bought the two expansions as well, perhaps they do have some cool Light Armor sets?

Thanks!

Comment: Orc's get +10 Heavy Armor & +5 Block, Enchanting, One-handed, Smithing, Two-handed so there's that to think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being an orc in light armor is no different from being any other race in light armor, except you'll miss out on the racial +10 bonus to heavy armor, but that only means it will take very slightly longer to max your light armor skill than heavy armor skill, because first levels in a skill are so much easier to attain than higher levels. If you want to figure out which type of armor is best for you, there is a number of questions on this topic.

- [What advantages do the different armor types provide?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35024/what-advantages-do-the-different-armor-types-provide)
- [Melee Combat: Heavy Armor vs. Light Armor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36546/melee-combat-heavy-armor-vs-light-armor?rq=1)
- [Light or Heavy Armor specialization help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36707/light-or-heavy-armor-specialization-help?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I personally was an Orc with heavy armor, mainly because of the +10 bonus which helped a lot. That and I weilded two handed weapons which for some reason works well with two-handed weapons.

I'd personally recommend heavy armor because of the bonus, means it wont take as long to level up, but if you like the light armor better and are gonna be sneaking a lot then try that.

The best thing to do is try both, try a bit of light armor doing as you normally would then try heavy armor for a bit - see what suits your play style.

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing a lightly armoured orc berzerker with 2h weapons decent enchanting, alteration, smithing and alchemy. He's a straight up monster in a fight. High stamina and health enchantment cast stone/iron flesh before charging in. I'd advise you get yourself to the lover stone near kolskegger mine soon as if you go for an inbitweener. It's way more fun to play a unique character build instead of your usual mage, theif/assassin Or warrior it gives it more flavour. I'd say go for it light armour is amazing fully perked. But I hate seeing an orc in glass or elven armour personally, Soooo wrong. I'm using scale until I get 100 smithing